# Autotype credentials to OpenVPN from KeePass

Tags: windows-7, windows, openvpn, keepass

I try to use Autotype feature of KeePass (2.16) on credentials window of OpenVPN (v3, windows 7 x64). But it is not input any characters.

I try Hotkey and menu item "Autotype" in KeePass nothing happens.

Is there any known issue or workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit late, but for others having this issue: KeePass needs to run as administrator in order to type into a program that also runs administrator (like OpenVPN). This solved the problem for me at least.

Comment: I don't remember running OpenVPN under admin account. But I checked and indeed KeePass is unable to send keystrokes to applications, launched from different user. I can't check openvpn now, but I think this will work, so I accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, but I think it's important that the OpenVPN login window is the last focused window before performing the Autotype. Make sure to try this:

1. Open the OpenVPN login prompt windows.
2. Tab to/open KeePass and perform Autotype (Ctrl-V)

Hope it works.

Comment: Problem is not actual now, than i don't use openvpn anymore. But just out of curiosity: What versions of OS, OpenVPN and KeePass you have?

Comment: Windows 8.1, OpenVPN Client v1.5.6 and KeePass v1.26

Comment: Well, thanks for input, but it quite different versions overall. keepass 1 is native C app, keepass 2 is .NET app, may be difference is here. If i ever use win8, i will test this combination.